# Android how to make Battery charging animation

Tags: android

I have some images in drawable folder. These images are different level of battery charging. I want to make animation of battery charging using these images. Mean I want to show battery is charging using these images. These are total 5 images of different level of charging battery. How I can do it?

Comment: You tell us. This kind of information should be very easy to find if you just google for it.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk can you give me any tutorial example

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try TransitionDrawable to accomplish this.

**Step 1 -** In an xml file in the drawable folder you create something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Set your different images for each drawable-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_2" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_3" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_4" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_5" />
</transition>
```

**Step 2 -** Then, in your View xml for the actual ImageView, set reference this TransitionDrawable in the `android:background` attribute.

**Step 3 -** In your code at appropriate place, initiate the transition as below:

```
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewObj.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(transitionTime);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using ViewFliper can be used to achieve this.
You can set all the battery label images in a imageview to the flipper to show them continuously.
You can have a look on this [blog post](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/viewflipper.php) for a good example and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) for android documentation.